# What's the correct wrong with my project template

Tags: templates, project, monodevelop

I'm trying to write some project and file templates for MonoDevelop (Android, Console and iOS) and can't seem to get the mpack files to install, I keep getting this error when installing the mpack file the monodevelop addin manager:

The add-in MonoDevelop.MonoAndroid.2.8.1.2 is trying to extend /MonoDevelop/Ide/About, but there isn't any add-in defining this extension point.

And here is my template, if you see anything silly, please let me know.

Thanks,
Kenny.

```
<Runtime>
    <Import file="__PreviewImage.png"/>
    <Import file="__TemplateIcon.png"/>
</Runtime>

<Dependencies>
    <Addin id="::MonoDevelop.Ide" version="2.8"/>
</Dependencies>

<Extension path="/MonoDevelop/Ide/ProjectTemplates">
    <ProjectTemplate id="iFactrCrossPlatformAndroid" file="iFactrCrossPlatformAndroid.xpt.xml" />
    <ProjectTemplate id="iFactrCrossPlatformTouch" file="iFactrCrossPlatformTouch.xpt.xml" />
    <ProjectTemplate id="iFactrAndroid" file="iFactrAndroid.xpt.xml" />
</Extension>
```

Comment: The only thing that's definitely silly is the title of your question. ;-)  That aside, I see two colons in this line `<Addin id="::MonoDevelop.Ide" version="2.8"/>` Is that correct?  I don't know Mono, but I don't normally see two colons like that.

Comment: That was what I found in the "latest" documentation, mdtool complains about the old "/" convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you have the correct attributes on your root  element. If so, the error would seem to indicate that you have an old copy of MonoDevelop.MonoAndroid.dll somewhere, and it's confusing the addin engine for some reason.

Note also that you need to import *all* the addin's files (except the manifest) to get them included in the mpack.

```
<Runtime>
    <Import file="__PreviewImage.png"/>
    <Import file="__TemplateIcon.png"/>
    <Import file="iFactrCrossPlatformAndroid.xpt.xml"/>
    <Import file="iFactrCrossPlatformTouch.xpt.xml"/>
    <Import file="iFactrAndroid.xpt.xml"/>
</Runtime>
```

Comment: Trying the Import thing now, are you supposed to include files the .xpt.xml files include?

Comment: Yes, the addin engine isn't automatically aware of files referenced by extension points or templates.

Comment: I have that work now, another thing I noticed is relative paths above the addin.xml file get packaged, but don't work, if I do something like ../Distribution it gets placed in the mpack as "Distribution" at the root, but then the file references in the templates don't work... (FYI, Sorry StackoverFlow about the bad title)

Comment: I really wouldn't recommend using relative paths above the addin file,  it's assumed that the addin file is at the root of the addin, and the addin gets unpacked into its own directory.